# SSRS Is Not Properly Displaying Query Results

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

When I run my query I get the following result.

'   200515200517   10'

This value is stored in varchar field in the table I am pulling from.

When I add this field to my report it is displaying the following:

'   2:00AM200517   10'

What do I need to do so the report will display the actual results and not change the value to a time.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it does not have some sort of format on that cell?

Comment: In the General tab it is set to "None - Plain text only" and on the Number tab it is set to Default.  I have deleted the field and re-added it to the table and still get the same results.

Comment: Just to check the obvious.. that SQL and the Reporting data source are one and the same? On the server as well ? I mean.. pointing to the same server for the data.

Comment: They are the same and after playing around I found my issue.  I am passing a date parameter as part of the query.  I added some formatting logic on the parameter and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found my issue.  I am passing a date parameter as part of the query.  I added some formatting logic on the parameter and that resolved the issue.